# Android GridView multi-select

Tags: android, gridview, multi-select

I'd like to do an activity with a GridView layout. I'll be able to multiselect items dragging my finger on the gridview's element (like [Ruzzle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.maginteractive.rumble.free) for example). When I raise my finger, I have to show how many items I have been selected.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but recently we had the same problem and we came up with something.

Let's suppose you want to change the color of the cells to green. You just need to call `GridView.setOnTouchListener` and implement an `OnTouchListener` similar to the following:

```
...
private final int SELECTED_CELL_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
private int mPosition = GridView.INVALID_POSITION;
private boolean mSelecting = false;
...
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    switch (action){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        GridView grid = (GridView)v;
        int position = grid.pointToPosition(x, y);
        if(position != GridView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); //Prevent parent from stealing the event
            View cellView = (View)grid.getItemAtPosition(position);
            switch (action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mSelecting = true;
                mPosition = position;
                cellView.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_CELL_COLOR);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mPosition != position) {
                    mPosition = position;
                    cellView.setBackgroundColor(SELECTED_CELL_COLOR);
                } else {
                    //Repeated cell, noop
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mSelecting = false;
                mPosition = GridView.INVALID_POSITION;
                //Here you could call a listener, show a dialog or similar
                break;
            }
        }else{
            if(mSelecting){
                mSelecting = false;
            }
        }
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        mSelecting = false;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```